# Ways to open an app in Android watch?

Tags: android, wear-os

I am working in project where we are trying to reduce the constraints involved while using multiple wearables. In order to open an app in an android watch, we need to touch the watch on its screen. So I am thinking of reducing that touch/click to open an app in android watch. Is there any other way to start an app in android watch? Like sending a notification from mobile to open an app in watch. Anything that can reduce the constraint of touching the watch screen will do. Please let me know any insights on this topic. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For one, you can use voice: "Ok Google, start blahblah". Secondly, it is possible to initiate start of an app from the companion phone (see this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34338668/2765813)) but I wouldn't call that less friction since I have to pull out my phone to do that,

Comment: Hi Ali, Thanks for the reply. I have a doubt. By sending a message from phone to watch, I believe you meant via messageapi. So to receive a message in watch, there should be an app running in watch right? But in my case I want to open an app in watch when no app is running in it. Please correct me if I am wrong. I am looking for ways in which I can trigger an app to open without much constraints.

Comment: Unless you have your own app running on the watch, you cannot receive messages sent to the watch from your phone app, hence cannot start a different app; you'd need to have a watch app as well.

Comment: But we can't keep any watch app running for a long time right? android kill the apps at some point of time. So basically we need to have a watch app running to receive messages or notifications. Also we can send notifications to watch to start an app but again we need click/open the notification to do that.Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You need to use WearableListenerService.